# Why is my python code running twice?

Tags: python

Whenever I type "no" for "Would you like to find the area of another shape?" it asks me the question again. Here is my code:-

```
def calculate_area():
  print "Welcome to the area calculator"
  user= raw_input("Enter the shape you would like to calculate the area of:").lower()

  def restart():
    answer= raw_input( "Would you like to find the area of another shape?('yes' or 'no')")
    if answer=="yes":
      calculate_area()
  def rerun():
    restart()


  if user== "rectangle":
    def calculate_rectangle():
      rect1= int(raw_input("Enter the length of the first side:"))
      rect2= int(raw_input("Enter the length of the second side:"))
      print "The area is:",float(rect1*rect2)
    calculate_rectangle()
    rerun()

  elif user== "square":
    def calculate_square():
      square=int(raw_input("Enter the length of the side:"))
      print "The area is:",float(square**2)
    calculate_square()
    rerun()


  elif user== "triangle":
    def calculate_triangle():
      triangle=int(raw_input("Enter the length of the base:"))
      triangle2=int(raw_input("Enter the height of the triangle:"))
      print "The area is:", float((0.5*triangle)*triangle2)
    calculate_triangle()
    rerun()


  elif user== "trapezoid":
    def calculate_trap():
      trapezoid=int(raw_input("Enter the length of base 1:"))
      trapezoid2=int(raw_input("Enter the length of base 2:"))
      trapezoid3=int(raw_input("Enter the height:"))
      print "The area is:", (float(trapezoid+trapezoid2)/2*float(trapezoid3))
    calculate_trap()
    rerun()

  elif user== "circle":
    def calculate_circle():
      circle=int(raw_input("Enter the radius:"))
      print "The area is:", (float((circle**2)*3.14))
    calculate_circle()
    rerun()

  elif user== "rhombus":
    def calculate_rhombus():
      rhombus1=int(raw_input("Enter the length of diagonal 1:"))
      rhombus2=int(raw_input("Enter the length of diagonal 2:"))
      print "The area is:", (float((rhombus1*rhombus2)/2))
    calculate_rhombus()
    rerun()    

  else:
    print "Shape not recognized"
  rerun()
```

This code is under "def restart" and runs twice whenever I type "no." Why is this happening?

Comment: because there is a `rerun()` at the end of the function...

Comment: Have you tried running it under a debugger, with a breakpoint on the "Would you like to find the area of another shape" line? Check the stack traces in both occurrences, and I think you'll know the answer.

Comment: your last ```rerun()``` is not indented under the final ```else``` block.

Comment: Please fix your indentation (and prune unnecessary code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last rerun()  should be inside the else statement:

```
  print ("Welcome to the area calculator")
  user = raw_input("Enter the shape you would like to calculate the area of:").lower()

  def restart():
    answer = raw_input( "Would you like to find the area of another shape?('yes' or 'no')")
    if answer == "yes":
      calculate_area()
  def rerun():
    restart()


  if user == "rectangle":
    def calculate_rectangle():
      rect1 = int(raw_input("Enter the length of the first side:"))
      rect2 = int(raw_input("Enter the length of the second side:"))
      print "The area is: ",float(rect1 * rect2)
    calculate_rectangle()
    rerun()

  elif user == "square":
    def calculate_square():
      square=int(raw_input("Enter the length of the side:"))
      print "The area is: ",float(square ** 2)
    calculate_square()
    rerun()


  elif user == "triangle":
    def calculate_triangle():
      triangle = int(raw_input("Enter the length of the base:"))
      triangle2 = int(raw_input("Enter the height of the triangle:"))
      print "The area is: ", float((0.5 * triangle) * triangle2)
    calculate_triangle()
    rerun()


  elif user == "trapezoid":
    def calculate_trap():
      trapezoid = int(raw_input("Enter the length of base 1:"))
      trapezoid2 = int(raw_input("Enter the length of base 2:"))
      trapezoid3 = int(raw_input("Enter the height:"))
      print "The area is: ", (float(trapezoid + trapezoid2) / 2 * float(trapezoid3))
    calculate_trap()
    rerun()

  elif user == "circle":
    def calculate_circle():
      circle = int(raw_input("Enter the radius:"))
      print "The area is: ", (float((circle ** 2)*3.14))
    calculate_circle()
    rerun()

  elif user == "rhombus":
    def calculate_rhombus():
      rhombus1 = int(raw_input("Enter the length of diagonal 1:"))
      rhombus2 = int(raw_input("Enter the length of diagonal 2:"))
      print "The area is: ", (float((rhombus1 * rhombus2) / 2))
    calculate_rhombus()
    rerun()    

  else:
    print "Shape not recognized"
    rerun()
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not see that over there. Putting inside the else, worked though.

Answer (score 3):

You call `rerun()` twice for every question:

```
if user== "rectangle":
    # ...
    rerun()

elif user== "square":
    # ...
    rerun()

# all other elif branches each have rerun()

else:
    print "Shape not recognized"
rerun()
```

You are relying on recursion here, but recursive functions *return*; when you type in `"No"`, `restart()` returns to `rerun()` which returns control to the point where it was called, so in one of your `if ... elif ...` branches. And *after* those branches you call `rerun()` again.

You should not be using recursion in the first place. Use an infinite loop instead:

```
print "Welcome to the area calculator"

while True:
    user = raw_input("Enter the shape you would like to calculate the area of:").lower()
    # execute their choice
    if user== "rectangle":
        # ...
    # etc.

    else:
        print "Shape not recognized"

    answer = raw_input( "Would you like to find the area of another shape?('yes' or 'no')")
    if answer != "yes":
        break
```

The `break` at the end ends the `while True` loop. If `yes` is entered, the `while` loop continues from the top, re-running the whole block.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `rerun()` at the end of your method.

Snippet:

```
  ...removed...
  else:
    print "Shape not recognized"
  rerun()
```